# Did any Muslim empire/kingdom have its capital in modern Pakistan except Lahore?

Tags: pakistan, islamic-history

As far as I know, the Muslim empires and kingdoms in the Indian subcontinent were either based in Lahore or Delhi.

- [List of cities in Pakistan by population](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_in_Pakistan_by_population)

I searched for the history of the top 10 largest cities in Pakistan. I only found Lahore and Peshawar had connections with some Muslim empires/kingdoms where Peshawar was used as the winter capital by some dynasties.

Did any Muslim empire/kingdom have its capital in modern Pakistan except Lahore?

*The various capitals of the Princely States that joined Pakistan do not count as  I am interested in the period before the British colonization.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Thatta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thatta) was the capital for multiple dynasties, including the Muslim [Soomra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soomra_dynasty) which ruled Sindh from there continuously in 1026–1356.

Comment: Can you add some details to this (just a paragraph or two)? Just a single sentence isn't really much of an answer... Also, are there any other examples other than Thatta.